# Chirpy doesn't recognise my config file???

Tags: chirpy

I have added a config file to my project called `mash.chirp.config` but there are no code behind files created when I save?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chirpy wasn't finding my config file because the paths should contain back slashses instead of forward slashes!

Works like a charm!